# What's best? Many small session values or one large one? PHP

Tags: php, session

I have about 15-20 permission settings that are loaded when a user logs in. These are each stored as a session with a value of 1 or 0.

I'm wondering, would it be better to have one session like `$_SESSION['permissions']` with a value of: `dothis:0,dothat:1,doanother:1`, etc. (one large string) which I can explode and seperate later on with PHP, or would it be best to have all these as separate sessions with just a value of 1 or 0?

Comment: What is wrong with storing them just as arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than a string to parse, store them as an array in `$_SESSION`. This makes it much easier to modify individual permissions without having to do piles of string operations.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['permissions'] = array();
$_SESSION['permissions']['dothis'] = TRUE;
$_SESSION['permissions']['dothat'] = FALSE;
$_SESSION['permissions']['doanother'] = TRUE;
```

**Addendum**

You might have figured this out already, but I thought I would add that it is easiest to interact with these via a few tiny functions. These will save a lot of typing (and typing errors), and make sure the values all end up as booleans.

```
function grant($permission) {
  $_SESSION['permissions'][$permission] = TRUE;
}
function revoke($permission) {
  $_SESSION['permissions'][$permission] = FALSE;
}
// Test if the user is allowed to do $permission
// FALSE if the permission isn't set
function user_can($permission) {
  return isset($_SESSION['permissions'][$permission]) ? $_SESSION['permissions'][$permission] : FALSE;
}
```

The you can just call them as:

```
grant('dothis');
revoke('dothat');
if (user_can('doanother')) {
   // congratulations you're allowed
}
```

Comment: Could it end up being a bad thing to have 20-30 different permissions in a session array? How many is too many?

Comment: As long as you have clear name keys for them and can keep them straight yourself, 20-30 isn't too many. You should also consider storing the values as boolean TRUE/FALSE rather than 1/0 for readability.

Comment: @user971230  See functions added above.

Answer (score 4):

I'd have an associative array that held all the permissions...

```
$_SESSION['permissions'] = array(
   ...
);
```

Comment: What I was going to say :) +1

Comment: Yeah I thought of that but forgot to ask about doing it that way. :) Thanks.